# Each spark worker only having 2 executors

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a single server with 3 nodes cluster and total core is 72

```
Node 1 - cassandra + spark master + 1 spark worker
Node 2 - cassandra + 1 spark worker
Node 2 - cassandra + 1 spark worker
```

but each spark worker takes only two executors

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CassandraSparkJavaDemo")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "ipaddress")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
                .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", true)
                .config("spark.cores.max", "3")                 
                .master("spark://ipaddress:7077").getOrCreate();
```

to read and aggregate using RDD in fifty-seven million records it tooks more than 1 hours (i am seeing each spark worker takes only two executors)

1. how to increase the number of executors using spark cassandre connector java api / any spark conf change ?
2. is there any other way to improve the performance ?

Comment: I guess you construct the RDD from a cassandra datasource. Could you please provide the code on how you do that? Is it just `val data = sc.cassandraTable(“my_keyspace”, “my_table”)`? What are you doing with this data? How do you aggregate?

Answer (score 3):

The first problem that I see here is that you set spark.cores.max=3. This tells spark to use only 3 cores from the 72 you have in total available. You can try the following to improve the performance:

1) Set spark.cores.max to a higher value e.g 63 you must let free some CPU resources for YARN on each node(in this case I decided to give three cores to each node your decision might be different)

2) Set spark.executor.instances to a higher value. In order to calculate the right number of executors you can do spark.cores.max / num_of_nodes = 63 / 3 = 21 which is the cores per node. Now you must consider that for each executor a higher value than 5cores causes HDFS I/O issues thus your final number of executors should be 21 / 4 ~ 5 executors. So finally you will have 5 executors on each node thus spark.executor.instances=15

You can find here some additional tips on howto increase the performance of your Spark cluster https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in customer end will not that much core. customer will have only 8 cores or 16 cores maximum. is there any other way to imporve the performance ?

now i changed the setup like bellow
Node 1 - cassandra + spark master + 2 spark worker
Node 2 - cassandra + 2 spark worker
Node 2 - cassandra + 2 spark worker

Comment: Hello Alex sorry for the late reply I just saw your comment, so if I understood well you have 3 Nodes available and 6 or 12 cores in total then I would have 6 executors with 1 core per executor(or 2 if 12 cores)